# different currencies in ci_merchant?

Tags: codeigniter, paypal, ci-merchant

I want to do a webshop, where users pay via paypal. Everything works perfectly, if I use the default currencies. However I want to pay with Hungarian Forint, which is not working.

In the merchant library I have found this:

```
public static $NUMERIC_CURRENCY_CODES = array(
    'AUD' => '036',
    'CAD' => '124',
    'EUR' => '978',
    'GBP' => '826',
    'NZD' => '554',
    'USD' => '840',
);
```

So I added a new line: 'HUF' => '348', but regardless when I want to pass the HUF parameter to the CI-Merchant, its not working. Matter of fact, I can change anything in this array, the results will be the same

This is how I pass the parameters:

```
$params = array(
'amount' => $osszeg,
'currency' => 'HUF',
'return_url' => 'something',
'cancel_url' => 'something');
```

(paypal supports Hungarian forint, so the problem is not there)

Is there any way to make this work? Thank you very much for your answers in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't use CI Merchant, it has been unsupported for nearly a year now. [Omnipay](https://github.com/omnipay/omnipay) is its replacement.

If you must use CI Merchant, then the `currency` parameter is correct. You don't need to add the numeric currency code, since paypal uses standard 3 letter currency codes. It's passed through to paypal here:

https://github.com/expressodev/ci-merchant/blob/master/libraries/merchant/merchant_paypal_base.php#L94

Now since you only say it's 'not working', I don't know what the actual problem is so can't really help diagnose. If there is an error message, what is it? I suspect that the currency is not enabled on your paypal account.